# Django context error in extended template called by view

Tags: python, django, templates, django-views

I'm working in Django 1.11 with Django-Jet template.

Now I need to extend template in order to showing some data retrived from a view. So, I defined my template and my view.
Here is the code:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 
from django.views.generic import View  
from django.template.context import RequestContext
from django.template import Context, Template 

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        op = str(self.kwargs['op']).strip().lower()
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']

        if op =='get':
            template='frontend/templates/show_my_data.html'
            return render_to_response(template,{'foo':'bar'})

        else:
            return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

**My simple template:**

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}
{% block content %}
{{ foo }}
{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
     'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
     'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')],
     'APP_DIRS': True,
     'OPTIONS': {
          'context_processors': [
              'django.template.context_processors.debug',
              'django.template.context_processors.request',
              'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
              'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

....

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

But when I run a test I get a key error:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/data_from_db/get/24/
Django Version:     1.11.2
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    

'user'

Exception Location:     /home/marco/sviluppo/myapp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/context.py in __getitem__, line 87
Python Executable:  /home/marco/sviluppo/myapp/myvenv/bin/python
```

So, I make some test, and I found that the problem is (maybe) in context variables. This is my base template that I need to be extended:

base.html

```
.....
{% if user.is_active and user.is_staff %}
     {% jet_get_menu as app_list %}
            {% if SIDE_MENU_COMPACT %}
                 {% for app in app_list %}
                   #print menu
                 {% endfor%}
.........
```

If I delete first condition: {% if user.is_active and user.is_staff %} there will be KeyError in {% jet_get_menu as app_list %}.
I'll show you some screen.

Normal admin template:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJNKq.jpg

View result if I do not delete {% if user.is_active and user.is_staff %} from base.html template

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCoZF.jpg

as you can see the page is totally empty: no menu labels, no login box in top right corner, ecc.

There seems to be no context variables like user, but I do not understand why.

Comment: Note that `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')],` looks wrong -- static files and Django templates are separate concepts, you should not be storing your templates in the static directory.

Comment: So, I have to move my template in other folder?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend moving any templates out of the `static` directory. However, this is a separate issue, it won't fix your `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `render` shortcut instead of `render_to_response` so that context processors are run.

```
if op == 'get':
    template = 'frontend/templates/show_my_data.html'
    return render(request, template, {'foo':'bar'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load jet_tags in every templates, you will be using them:

```
{% load jet_tags %}
```

Comment: def get_menu_items(context):
    pinned_apps = PinnedApplication.objects.filter(user=context['user'].pk).values_list('app_label', flat=True) in utils.py is the problem I think